Getting 403 forbidden error when we chosen the customer once asagent is logged in Spartacus ASM module
Getting 403 forbidden error when we chosen the customer once asagent is logged in Spartacus ASM module.
{
"errors" : [ {
"message" : "Access is denied",
"type" : "ForbiddenError"
} ]
}
Tried by adding customermamagergroup to the employee.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
